# Get grandparent directory name in gulp

Tags: node.js, gulp

I'm tying to get get the grandparentparent directory of my `gulpfile.js` file.
This is my folder structure : `airi\Gulp\gulpfile.js` 
I want to get the folder with name `airi`.

```
gulp.task('serve', ['sass'], function () {
    browserSync.init({
        proxy: "http://localhost/" + var_that_stores_name_airi,
    });
});
```

`var_that_stores_name_airi` would be my variable that contains the folder name I want ( ie: airi ).I want this so that I can append it my browsersync proxy url.
How do I do this in gulp ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be fancy, this will do it:

```
const path = require('path');

let dir = path.relative(path.parse(path.dirname(__dirname)).dir, path.parse(__dirname).dir)
```

or try the simpler

```
let dir = path.parse(path.resolve(__dirname, '../')).name;
```

[Thanks to @DerekNguyen's excellent comment below.]

This will also do it:

```
const path = require('path');

let dir = __dirname.split(path.sep);
dir = dir[dir.length - 2];
console.log("dir = " + dir);


gulp.task('serve', ['sass'], function () {

  let dir = __dirname.split(path.sep);
  dir = dir[dir.length - 2];

  browserSync.init({
    proxy: "http://localhost/" + dir,
  });
});
```

Comment: I just want to add that `path.parse(path.resolve(__dirname, '../../')).name` will do the job as well & somewhat more intuitive than path.relative

Comment: Nice, but you went up one level too far - it looks like the OP wants to get the grandparent directory to where the gulpfile.js is.  So path.parse(path.resolve(__dirname, '../')).name

Comment: Oh you are right -- I was thinking of granparent dir of current dir. One `../` is indeed enough

Comment: Both of the answers where correct, but from @DerekNguyen
 ``path.parse(path.resolve(__dirname, '../../')).name`` what does ``.name`` do ?

Comment: path.parse() returns an object.  One of the keys in that object is "name", "dir", "base", etc.  See https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_parse_path So the object returned by path.parse has a "name" key which can be a filename or a directory name depending on what you are parsing.  In this case the object being parsed was a full path that ended with the directory you were interested in, so "name" just returned that last directory.